# Prime factorization of numbers up to $10^{12}$

Tags: algorithms, prime-factorization

How do I find **prime factorization** of numbers that are **very large (up to $\mathbf{10^{12}}$)**.
Actually I need **powers of the primes** that we get after prime factorization of a number. 
I cant use the Sieve of Eratosthenes because of its space complexity. 
Please suggest me a way to do this!
Actually I need to find prime factorization of all numbers in a range and that range contains at max **10**<sup>**5**</sup> elements.

**Note from Comments:** The OP is motivated by an exercise in which, for each $n$ in a range of size $10^5$, the divisor of $n$ with the largest number of divisors is selected, and then its divisor with the largest number of divisors is selected, etc. until $1$ is reached.  The number of divisors of these selected numbers is totaled.  [A couple of points are unclear: is the total to be found over the entire range, or reported as a sum for each $n$ in the range?  Is the number of divisors of $n$ to be included in such sums?  It would help if the OP included a link to the original problem statement, but it is clear why a prime factorization of each $n$ will allow the divisor count to be quickly computed.]

Comment: $10^{12}$ is not "very large". wolframalpha can do this in milliseconds - for example, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+108804542843

Comment: To find complete prime factorizations of all integers in a consecutive range, sieving is a natural approach.  Your objection to the Sieve of Eratosthenes "because of its space complexity" doesn't seem well founded: [a significant proportion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) of integers in any such range will be primes. Their prime factorization consists of identifying and reporting them.  This [blog post](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/7262) discusses optimizing a sieve algorithm for extracting the full prime factorization after finding all the primes in a range.

Comment: @hardmath can you please explain it more? In seive, i need to save numbers smallest prime factor, so how can i store it for 10^12 numbers?

Comment: Some ideas on performing a sieve of Eratosthenes on ranges that are subsets of a longer range can be found by searching for "segmented sieve of Eratosthenes".  So instead of doing all $10^{12}$ integers at once, one might split that range into blocks of size $10^6$.  Then you are looking at storing one million blocks of length one million each, if you indeed needed to perform the computations for all $10^{12}$ integers.  Is this something you'd like to learn more about?

Comment: @hardmath let me tell u my real ques. for all the numbers in the given range, i have to select a the divisor that has maximum number of divisors. then repeat this step for that number, until we reach 1. Finally i need to find sum of number of divisors of all the selected numbers.

Comment: Okay, so let's clear up the "real question". (1)  Are you counting all divisors of integer $n$? Or prime divisors that are distinct? Or prime divisors with multiplicity? (2) Where did you get this question?

Comment: @hardmath we need all divisors.

Comment: Regarding this: *the divisor of n with the largest number of divisors is selected, and then its divisor with the largest number of divisors is selected, etc. until 1 is reached. The number of divisors of these selected numbers is totaled.* - wouldn't this just be the $(a-1)th$ triangle number where $a$ is the number of prime factors of $n$?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're aware that factoring large integers is not a trivial computational operation. Any technique will involve some kind of search or sieve.

In your case, notice that you only need to look for primes up to $10^6$, which is feasible by precomputing or downloading a table of primes and then performing trial division.

Comment: ya that will work for a single number, but actually i want to find prime factorization of numbers in a range, and that range can contain  10^15 numbers. How to do that?

Comment: @TanujYadav:  You said a range would contain up to $10^5$ numbers in the Question itself, but now you say "that range can contain" $10^{15}$ numbers.  Note that this is also inconsistent with the premise of "numbers up to $10^{12}$" in the Question's title and body.

Comment: sorry, it is 10^5